# Flink job submission to Multi-VM Flink Cluster fails with JobSubmissionException, CompletionException and Connection Refused error

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I can launch a Flink cluster (version 1.17.x) on my laptop with 1 Job Manager and 3 Task Managers. The cluster starts, jobs can be submitted correctly on the localhost (my laptop).

Next step is to launch this cluster on 4 VMs -  1 Master VM (for the Job Manager) and 3 Worker VMs (for Task Managers). I am not using YARN, K8s or Docker on any of these VMs.

The cluster starts up fine using `"${FLINK_HOME}"/bin/start-cluster.sh`. i.e., running this on the command line on the Master VM does the expected - it starts the job manager on the Master and then starts 1 Task Manager on each Worker VM. (ssh connectivity between Master and Worker VMs is setup).

However, job submission(`"${FLINK_HOME}"/bin/flink run myapp.jar`) fails with the following exceptions:

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not upload job files.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.client.ClientUtils.uploadJobGraphFiles(ClientUtils.java:86)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.job.JobSubmitHandler.lambda$uploadJobGraphFiles$4(JobSubmitHandler.java:195)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not connect to BlobServer at address localhost/127.0.0.1:37452
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobClient.<init>(BlobClient.java:103)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.job.JobSubmitHandler.lambda$null$3(JobSubmitHandler.java:199)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.client.ClientUtils.uploadJobGraphFiles(ClientUtils.java:82)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:615)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobClient.<init>(BlobClient.java:97)
    ... 13 more
]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient.parseResponse(RestClient.java:536)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient.lambda$submitRequest$3(RestClient.java:516)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1072)
    ... 4 more
```

Looking at the DEBUG level logs on the Master (Job Manager) and the Workers (Task Managers) ... it looks like the Task Managers on the Worker VMS are all registered with the Job Manager on the Master VM (The Job Manager logs shows the Task Managers). The Web UI reflects this too.
Hence, it is ONLY the job submission that's failing with this "Could not connect to Blob Server" exception.

1. Is there a reference implementation of a Multi-VM Flink Cluster (NOT on Docker)?
2. How should `taskmanager.*.*.*` properties in `flink-conf.yaml` be configured for a multi-VM cluster?
3. Does a multi-VM flink cluster need shared storage directory? If so is there any documentation on configuring this?

Comment: [@user1831595](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831595/user1831595 "@user1831595"), did you find any solution to this. Me too stuck with this error.